# How to run IlDasm on .obj files?

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, clr

I have compiled `.obj` files from `c++/cli` compiler (`.obj` files were compiled from source with `/clr` option). Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) says that is possible to run `ildasm` to see some metadata of `.obj` files. But command `ildasm /metadata foo.obj` says error with message - `ildasm supports only PE files in graphic mode`. Ildasm was taken from `msvc 2015`. What's wrong with my command?

Comment: That is not what it says.  The option is valid only for a .lib file.  /objectfile then lets you pick one specific .obj file embedded in the .lib file.  How this actually could be useful is very murky, the C++/CLI build system does not permit generating static libraries.

Comment: @HansPassant, oh, thanks. But Is there any way to check managed tokens of obj file (to cope with LNK2022 error?)

Comment: Dumpbin.exe /symbols on an .obj file shows "External" symbols.  Proving the absence of a symbol is not usually very helpful, at best you could identify a name mangling issue.

Answer (score 1):

The docs provided are a bit obtuse, but basically you cannot ildasm on an object file--in graphical mode.

However, according to: [here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/97a54f05-0bdf-4c24-8d32-92a452c4c306/trying-to-solve-error-lnk2022)

You can run ildasm.exe on object files in text-mode.

> ildasm /text /tokens myobject.obj